# How can I have shared scope and pass data in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the angular directive I have this

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template:'<div>{{myindex}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log('test', scope.myindex)
    },
   controller: 'myDirController'
  };
})
```

I use like this

`<my-dir> </my-dir>`

Now as I want to use it in different templates, I have one function which I want to call like this

```
// this is inside myDirController        
test: function($scope){
          $scope.myFunction();
        }
```

Now basically I want to call  `$scope.myFunction();`

This works fine if I have  `$scope.myFunction();` defined in parent controller.

Buy it's not reusable as in my other controller I want to call  `$scope.myFunction2();`.

*So* I want something so that I can pass the function name in directive

`<my-dir fname="myFunction"> </my-dir>`

and that gets called in my directive

**The thing is I can't use isolated scope as I need to have access to parent $scope**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to call  $scope.myFunction();
>
> [my directive is] not reusable as in my other controller i want to call  $scope.myFunction2();
>
> SO i want something so that i can pass the function name in directive:
>
> `<my-dir fname="myFunction"> </my-dir>`

**1)** The attributes in your custom tag are available in the link function, so you can save the value of the fname attribute for future use:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  scope.data = {fname: attrs.fname};
},
```

**2)** An object's properties can be retrieved using dot notation, e.g. `$scope.fname`, but the properties can also be retrieved using array notation, e.g. `$scope[fname]`, where fname is a string. And if `$scope[fname]` is a function, you can execute it by writing `$scope[fname]()`:

```
app.controller('MyDirCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    var fname = $scope.data.fname;
    $scope[fname]();  //fname property not found in current scope, so parent scope is searched
  };
});
```

....

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <my-dir fname="funcInCtrl1"></my-dir>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <my-dir fname="funcInCtrl2"></my-dir>
  </div>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.funcInCtrl1 = function() {
    console.log('funcInCtrl1 called...');
  };
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.funcInCtrl2 = function() {
    console.log('funcInCtrl2 called...');
  };
}]);

app.controller('MyDirCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    var fname = $scope.data.fname;
    $scope[fname]();
  };
}]);

app.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template:'<div ng-click="test()">click me</div>',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.data = {fname: attrs.fname};
    },

    controller: 'MyDirCtrl', 
  }
})
```

And, here it is with *Controller as* syntax:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1 as ctrl1">
    <my-dir fname="ctrl1.funcInCtrl1"></my-dir>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2 as ctrl2">
    <my-dir fname="ctrl2.funcInCtrl2"></my-dir>
  </div>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function() {
  this.funcInCtrl1 = function() {
    console.log('funcInCtrl1 called...');
  };
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function() {
  this.funcInCtrl2 = function() {
    console.log('funcInCtrl2 called...');
  };
});

app.controller('MyDirCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.test = function() {
    var fnames = $scope.data.fname.split('.');
    var ctrl_name = fnames[0];
    var func_name = fnames[1];
    $scope[ctrl_name][func_name]();
  };
}]);

app.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template:'<div ng-click="mydirCtrl.test()">click me</div>',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.data = {fname: attrs.fname};
    },

    controller: 'MyDirCtrl', 
    controllerAs: 'mydirCtrl'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory and create different directives with this factory that use your specific function.

```
module.service('DirectiveFactory', function() {
  this.create = function(fn) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      template:'<div>{{myindex}}</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log('test', scope.myindex)
      },
     controller: function($scope) {
       // your specific function
       fn();
     }
    };
  };
});

module.directive('my-dir-1', function(DirectiveFactory) {
  function fn1() {
    console.log('my special function call1');
  }
  return DirectiveFactory.create(fn1);
});

module.directive('my-dir-2', function(DirectiveFactory) {
  function fn1() {
    console.log('my special function call2');
  }
  return DirectiveFactory.create(fn2);
});
```

In your template you'd use:

```
<my-dir-1></my-dir1>

<my-dir-2></my-dir2>
```

Comment: That looks too much. Is there is any cleaner way. Rather i was thinking of making general function in controller called `loadData` which itself can all any function required rather bloat the directive

Comment: Pretty clean approach, IMHO. It keeps functionality separate. Similar functionality is in the "base" directive and all deviation is in the "sub" directives. Obviously, without any further information on your specific use case, I can't suggest anything else...